# Can't change button color because it is not defined - Python .Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

trying to configure button so that it changes color once clicked.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def  buttonsMake():
    for c in range(10):
        for r in range(3):
            movieSeats=Button(root, text="Empty", bg="green", fg="white", 
width=5, height=1, command=lambda c=c, r=r:[redClick(c, r)])
            movieSeats.grid(row=r,column=c)


def redClick(c, r):
    movieSeats.configure(bg="red")



buttonsMake()
root.mainloop()
```

I expect it to change color

Here's the error:

```
movieSeats=Button(root, text="Empty", bg="green", fg="white", width=5, 
height=1, command=lambda c=c, r=r:[redClick(c, r)])
  File "C:/Users/----/Downloads/test2.py", line 21, in redClick
    movieSeats.configure(bg="red")
NameError: name 'movieSeats' is not defined
```

Comment: use button `{}` to correctly format code.

Comment: you don't need list in lambda - you can do `lambda c=c, r=r:redClick(c, r)`

Comment: `movieSeats` is local variable in both functions. You have to use `global movieSeats` in `buttonsMake()` to create global variable.

Comment: BTW: you assign all buttons to the same variable so you have access only to last button. You have to keep buttons on list. Or send it to `redClick` as parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`movieSeats` is local variable in `buttonsMake()` so it doesn't exist in `redClick` and you get error `name 'movieSeats' is not defined`

You have to use `global movieSeats` in `buttonsMake()` to create global variable.

---

**BTW:**

You assing all buttons to the same variable so you have access only to last button. You can keep all buttons on list or send it to `redClick` as parameter

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def make_buttons():

    for c in range(10):
        for r in range(3):
            btn = tk.Button(root, text="Empty")
            btn['command'] = lambda c=c, r=r, b=btn:red_click(c, r, b)
            btn.grid(row=r,column=c)

def red_click(c, r, btn):
    btn.configure(bg="red")

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

make_buttons()

root.mainloop()
```